# Vue js Preloader doesnt stop loading

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am really new to vue so this question maybe is stupid and i did it all wrong.

First response to my search for a "Vue Preloader" whas

https://github.com/Bot-Academia/Vue-ui-preloader

Installed it like it said but after that it doesnt stop
My next step would be ok the hide it when page is loaded

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      console.log('yolo');
  })
}
});
```

So now is the point where i got confused

```html
<div data-v-768a39c6="" id="overlay-circular" style="background-color: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.8);"><div class="loader-circular"></div>
```

How do i $( "#overlay-circular" ).hide() this in vue ? and is it the right way to do or did i screw up in the first place and thats why it wont stop ?

Thanks for your time and help
Best regards
Limuz

Comment: try adding a reference to the div <div data-v-768a39c6="" id="overlay-circular" ref="overlayCircular" style="background-color: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.8);"><div class="loader-circular"></div> and then type `this.$refs.overlayCircular.hide()`.

Comment: Thank you i broke it yesterday completly and gave up i believe i screwed up i loaded the app js deffer and the content is loaded befor the preloader fires i should have tought of that again thank you for the help!

Comment: I am happy to hear that. Let me put it as an answer and then you can accept it. Is that ok?

Comment: ofc thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a reference to the div

```js
<div data-v-768a39c6="" id="overlay-circular" ref="overlayCircular" style="background-color: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.8);"><div class="loader-circular">
```

Then type `this.$refs.overlayCircular.hide()`